# How to wait for a long period of time webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ok so my question is 'How should I wait for an extended period of time say 15 min with webdriver'. Is it viable to use Thread.Sleep(60*1000*15)? What potential issues could come from having the driver just wait for a long time does it get stale?

The reason I have to write a test with such a wait is that I am testing some integration with one of our 3rd parties. We submit some work to them and generally speaking it can take anywhere from a few min to around 15 min for the work to be picked up and processed.

That being said I have been thinking about the more costly approach and use explicit waits with expected conditions and just use Driver.Navigate().Refresh() until I see the elements I expect. My concern here is that if I take this approach there will be a portion of the test where it would be refreshing the browser ever 10 or so seconds for a duration of 5-10 min. Which of these approaches seems better. Are there dangers of refreshing the browser so much could the driver 'loose' the browser? Not really a fan of either of these approaches so any other suggestions id be open to.

Comment: if you use Thread.Sleep(60*1000*15) you'll sto the thread. It's not so ugly but if the server web has an application pool you'll take up one slot. If you'll call many times the same server in that 15min you'll receive one application pool unavailable

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Thread.Sleep, because it blocks the thread. The second approach is better, because operation can be finished in 5, or 10min - you don't have to wait 15mins. In fact, I've done something similar in the past.

Another option would be to use System.Threading.Timer to check for result every Nmin and pass/fail a test. This will require some effort to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any other indication that the integration has finished processing aside from the element/s showing up on the web page? E.g. a file being created somewhere etc.

If not, then I would definitely be taking the second approach - it is a much better approach since you will only wait roughly the amount of time you need to wait and also it will not bomb if for some reason it takes more than the maximum amount you specified. I would still set an upper limit e.g. 20 or 30 minutes for the test to fail if the element is not showing.

There should be no issue with keeping your browser open and refreshing as long as the web application is stable. And BTW this is actually quite a common scenario in test automation, unfortunately for third party integration there is not much else you can do.

in C# it looks something like this-

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an element if found, otherwise returns null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="by"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal IWebElement FindElementIfExists(By by)
    {
        IWebElement element = null;
        try
        {
            element = FindElement(@by);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {

        }

        return element;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var timeout = 30 // in minutes
        browser.GoTo<Page>();
        while (FindElementIfExists(By.Id("id")) == null && stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes < timeout)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30); // sleep for 30 seconds
            browser.GoTo<Page>();
        }

        if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes >= timeout)
            // fail test

        // continue test             
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution was simple to implement and works like a charm. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Thanks for accepting my answer - I would appreciate a vote up if not too much to ask :-)

Comment: I would gladly upvote but do not have a reputation of 15 yet... When I get there I gladly will.

Comment: Ha ha thanks. You can upvote now and it will count when you reach that reputation ;-)

Comment: well in that case when I get there you shall recieve your upvote because I already tried to :)